# mysql mass insert into many to many table

Tags: mysql

I have introduced a new many-to-many table and would like to know if there is a way to do a SELECT/INSERT with 2 tables.

Tables:

1. users
2. groups
3. user_groups (empty)

How can I insert all of the users into each group? E.g populating the user_groups tables with everything.

user_groups contains forien keys for both users and groups.

Update with more details showing the table structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `group_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_groups` (
  `user_group_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_group_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I could do this in a PHP script by looping through all of the users but just wondering if this is possible with sql only

Comment: Update with literally everything, or some more specific data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an INSERT...SELECT.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

You just need to find a way to select the dataset you want, which if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to add every user to every group. An INNER JOIN with an always true join condition will match every user to every group.

So the select would be something like

`SELECT users.user_id, groups.group_id FROM users INNER JOIN groups ON 1=1`

So the whole query should be something like

`INSERT INTO user_groups (user_id,group_id) SELECT users.user_id, groups.group_id FROM users INNER JOIN groups ON 1=1`

Comment: Perfect, I had never thought of doing the 1=1. I was trying to select from 2 tables which wasnt working.